# how do i stop box sizing border moving content around

Tags: html, css, border-box

I am using lots of divs that have absolutely positioned children divs inside them.

What I am trying to do is put a border inside the div but to not interact with the absolute positioned elements inside.

(almost like a floating border)

I've tried using outline but that doesn't work as it really need it inside the .box divs

I've also tried box shadow inset but this still moves the content.

Is there any way for me to do this?

```css
    .box {
        height:200px;
        width:100px;
        background:red;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    
    .box:hover {
        border:22px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        box-sizing:border-box;
    }
    .silly {
        color:#ffffff;
        position:absolute;
        left:0px;
        top:0;
    }
    .silly1 {
        color:#ffffff;
        position:absolute;
        left:30px;
        top:160px;
    }
    .silly2 {
        color:#ffffff;
        position:absolute;
        right:0;
        top:90px;
    }
    .silly3 {
        color:#ffffff;
        position:absolute;
        left:10px;
        top:40px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="box">

        <div class="silly">I am box</div>
        <div class="silly1">1</div> 
        <div class="silly2">2</div> 
        <div class="silly3">3</div> 
    </div>
    
    <div class="box">
        <div class="silly">I am box</div>
        <div class="silly1">1</div> 
        <div class="silly2">2</div> 
        <div class="silly3">3</div> 
    </div>
    
    <div class="box">
        <div class="silly">I am box</div>
        <div class="silly1">1</div> 
        <div class="silly2">2</div> 
        <div class="silly3">3</div> 
    </div>
```

[here is the DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/susannalarsen/m0cdwph2/)

Comment: See this, https://jsfiddle.net/m0cdwph2/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an extra child div inside of the `.box` element and apply the current `.box:hover` styling to it. Make sure this new child div is `position:absolute` to remove it from the 'flow'.

As an aside, I tend to apply `box-sizing: border-box;` to all elements using the `*` selector.

```css
*{
  
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
.box {
        height:200px;
        width:100px;
        background:red;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    
    .border{
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      }
    .box:hover .border {
        border:22px solid black;
    }
    .silly {
        color:#ffffff;
        position:absolute;
        left:0px;
        top:0;
    }
    .silly1 {
        color:#ffffff;
        position:absolute;
        left:30px;
        top:160px;
    }
    .silly2 {
        color:#ffffff;
        position:absolute;
        right:0;
        top:90px;
    }
    .silly3 {
        color:#ffffff;
        position:absolute;
        left:10px;
        top:40px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="box">
        <div class="border"></div>
        <div class="silly">I am box</div>
        <div class="silly1">1</div> 
        <div class="silly2">2</div> 
        <div class="silly3">3</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: while adding  `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` is a good practice when you first start development, retroactively adding it could cause any sort of layout issues.

Comment: This is an excellent point, however personally i wouldn't dream of starting a project without using it :)

Answer (score 2):

create a container for your `box` and add `position: relative` to it, instead of adding it to `box`:

```css
        .box-container {
            position:relative;
        }


        .box {
            height:200px;
            width:100px;
            background:red;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            display:inline-block;
        }
        
        .box:hover {
            border:22px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            box-sizing:border-box;
        }
        .silly {
            color:#ffffff;
            position:absolute;
            left:0px;
            top:0;
        }
        .silly1 {
            color:#ffffff;
            position:absolute;
            left:30px;
            top:160px;
        }
        .silly2 {
            color:#ffffff;
            position:absolute;
            right:0;
            top:90px;
        }
        .silly3 {
            color:#ffffff;
            position:absolute;
            left:10px;
            top:40px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="box-container">
    <div class="box">

        <div class="silly">I am box</div>
        <div class="silly1">1</div> 
        <div class="silly2">2</div> 
        <div class="silly3">3</div> 
    </div>
</div>
```